# Get rid window with selenium server

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

Hello. I don't want to see this window output app. How can i get rid of that and implement it into app.
After close app selenium with chrome driver should also quit

Comment: Why do you not want to see this window? This window IS your app, or at least the app that is controlling your browser.  It should close, if your app correctly terminates Selenium, if not, then are you sure Driver.Quit is being called?

Comment: no i want to move this console to console(textbox) in my app, thats it

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://siteobservers.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201989070-Start-selenium-server-with-additional-command-line-arguments) shows you how to run Selenium from the command line and pass in various arguments including `-log <logFileName>` which will redirect that output to a file, which you can then load into your app.